# How to run a recent version of pypy (e.g., 2.3.1) on Heroku, Rackspace, AWS?

Tags: heroku, numpy, amazon-web-services, pypy, rackspace

I'd like to use pypy 2.3.1 as a runtime env. for a Flask app with numpy. I've tested this on Heroku, but it only support pypy v. 1.9. Has anyone had luck with running a recent v. of pypy, e.g., pypy 2.3.1, on either Heroku, Rackspace, AWS or similar?

Answer (score 1):

On an Ubuntu Rackspace cloud server (or any other Ubuntu machine) you can get the latest version of PyPy by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypy/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pypy pypy-dev
```